# Translations with Django 1.5.11 and Apache

Tags: django, apache, internationalization

I am using django 1.5.11 with translations having the locale folder not in the site directory. I used the LOCALE_PATHS variable to set the correct folder. When I start my application using runserver, either in my machine or the server, the translation work correctly. The problems come when I do it with wsgi. My django app is served with apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi compiled with python 2.7.10 with the following wsgi script:

```
import os
import sys
import site
site.addsitedir('/path/to/virtualenvs/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/app/folder/')
sys.path.append('/settings/folder/')
sys.path.append('/virtualenvs/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/virtualenvs/bin')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/virtualenvs/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

when started apache the translation is not working, it looks like the LOCALE_PATHS is ignored and look for the translation in the site folder instead. I don't understand where this behaviour is coming from (apache mod_wsgi maybe?). Has anyone else experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this issue, albeit with Django 1.8.15. It seems that you'll have to provide an absolute path for the `LOCALE_PATHS` for this to work with Apache. Relative paths do not seem to work on the server, while they do work locally. Not sure what causes this behavior though.

Comment: You can never assume that the current working directory of any WSGI server will actually be where your code is. To ensure you code is portable you should always use an absolute path. Try though to calculate that from some anchor though, such as ``os.path.dirname(__file__)`` so you aren't hard coding the base directory.